# Why JDBI 3 @ColumnName annotation doesn't work?

Tags: java, orm, jdbi

I want to use jdbi 3 @ColumnName annotations to map column name of the table and java bean field, but at runtime jdbi throws an exception.
My question is why is the exception thrown? Is my usage incorrect? How to solve this problem?
Thanks

Database table:

```
CREATE TABLE `department` (
  `id` bigint(20)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `business_system` tinyint(4)  NOT NULL ,
  `functional` tinyint(4)  NOT NULL ,
  `remark` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Java Bean:

```
@Data
public class Department {
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @ColumnName("business_system")
    private Integer businessSystem;

    @NotNull
    @ColumnName("functional")
    private Integer functional;

    @Max(value = 200)
    private String remark;
  }
```

JDBI Update:

```
@Override
public Long create(Department department) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO department (name, business_system, functional, remark)"
        + "VALUES (:name, :business_system, :functional, :remark)";

return jdbi.withHandle(handle -> handle.createUpdate(sql)
    .bindBean(department)
    .executeAndReturnGeneratedKeys()
    .mapTo(Long.class)
    .findOnly());
```

}

Unit test running result：

```
org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToExecuteStatementException: Unable to 
execute, no named parameter matches 'business_system'. [statement:"INSERT INTO 
department (name, business_system, functional, remark)VALUES (:name, 
:business_system, :functional, :remark)", rewritten:"INSERT INTO department 
(name, business_system, functional, remark)VALUES (:name, :business_system, 
:functional, :remark)", parsed:"ParsedSql{sql='INSERT INTO department (name, 
business_system, functional, remark)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', 
parameters=ParsedParameters{positional=false, parameterNames=[name, 
business_system, functional, remark]}}", 
arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{}, finder:[{lazy bean property arguments 
"Department(id=null, name=test, businessSystem=2, functional=2, 
remark=test)"]}]
```

Answer (score 15):

Jdbi maintainer here. Four misunderstandings are conspiring to make your code not work:

First, `@ColumnName` defines a one-way mapping used only for mapping column names to object properties/fields/constructor parameters. So `BeanMapper` will honor the `@ColumnName` annotation, but `bindBean()` ignores it.

Second, `BeanMapper` only detects `@ColumnName` on getters and setters--not fields. 
Since you are using Lombok's `@Data` annotation, the `@ColumnName` annotation is actually put on the field. Lombok has a super ugly way to specify annotations to the getter or setter:

```
@NotNull
@Getter(onMethod=@__(@ColumnName("business_system")))
private Integer businessSystem;

@NotNull
@Getter(onMethod=@__(@ColumnName("functional")))
private Integer functional;
```

Third, `bindBean()` binds named parameters based on bean property names, not column names. So your named parameters should be in `:camelCase` instead of `:snake_case`:

```
INSERT INTO department (name, business_system, functional, remark)
VALUES (:name, :businessSystem, :functional, :remark)
--                      ^ camel case property name
```

Finally, Jdbi 3 already matches up snake-case column names to camel-case property names out of the box. For example: a column `foo_bar` would automatically be mapped to a `fooBar` property, no `@ColumnName` annotation required.

Comment: Per the Lombok 1.18.30 javadoc regarding `onMethod`:

> The syntax for this feature depends on JDK version (nothing we can do about that; it's to work around javac bugs). up to JDK7: @Getter(onMethod=@__({@AnnotationsGoHere})) from JDK8: @Getter(onMethod_={@AnnotationsGohere}) // note the underscore after onMethod.


So, one the examples would be:

```java
@NotNull
@Getter(onMethod_={@ColumnName("business_system")})
private Integer businessSystem;
```